# Cvc-elt.1 cannot find the declaration of element 'beans' while running jar from Batch File

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, batch-file

I have a maven project with package structure as follows :

[image]

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com</groupId>
  <artifactId>WMR-API-AR2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <name>WMR-API-AR2</name>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <springframework.version>4.1.2.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <oracle.connector.version>11.2.0</oracle.connector.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Oracle Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>${oracle.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>   
    <!-- Apache POI Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
         <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
         <version>3.17</version>
     </dependency>       
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
         <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
         <version>3.17</version>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                <descriptorRefs>
                           <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                   </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.Application</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                   <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
               </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>  
  </build>
</project>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">

    <bean id="mailProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"> 
        <property name="location" value="file:///C:/Users/abhishek.roy/eclipse-workspace/WMR-API-AR2/config/jdbc.properties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="datasourcedev04" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver_class_name}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${dev4.url}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${dev4.username}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${dev4.password}"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="datasourcelocal" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver_class_name}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${local.url}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${local.username}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${local.password}"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The idea is to build the project as an executable **.jar** *(present inside lib folder)* and run it from a **.batch** file *(present inside bin folder)*

The code works perfectly when executed in Eclipse. However when I try to run it from the .batch file, I encounter the following exception :

[image] 
I am unable to figure out the reason behind this exception. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ok, so where is the batch file content?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Here is the batch file code

`java -jar ..\lib\WMR-API-AR2-0.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar`